# Display Javascript Code In PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I Have A problem In displaying JS Code In PHP
My Code Is

```
<?php
    if($result)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo "$('#Err').hide()</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo "$('#Err').show()</script>";
    }
?>
```

I Am Using XAMPP For running Code When I Run This Code It Will Not Display 
I Don't know what's the problem
plz tell me 
Thanks!

Comment: The way you have written your code tells me you don't know about escaping quotes in strings. If you don't know such a basic thing, I'm not hopeful that you tried *View Source* to see what PHP is outputting.

Comment: When you 'view source' of the resulting page in the browser is the <script> tag in there at all and just not working like you expect or is it completely missing?

Comment: The script tag is there for me in FF12, and I get a JS error, "$ is not defined." Have you included your jQuery dependency file? Also, if you're not already, load up Firefox and add the 'Firebug' extension, it will make debugging Javascript much easier.

Comment: The given answers are correct. However, my personal preference is to always have static JavaScript that acts on some dynamic bit of data via a hidden field. That way you can easily cache the JS into external files.

Comment: I put an answer below. Try not to use echo when throwing html or scripts, it's a good practice for PHP development, and also you won't need to worry about escaping (and so far, hardcoding) other languages.

Comment: You code should just work. It looks more or less it is not executed at all, but from what you've shared with your question, nothing more can be said.

Comment: I have Got It But There Is A little problem i am using this code in post with action on default page  when submit is clicked and i print the Err Tag Than There Will Be A very Short delay The Page Reloads Again And It Is Hidden Again As By default It Is Hidden when i print it through alert() delay occurs and i can see the printed tag but i want to do it without alert() function 
Kindly tell Me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` sign as follows:

```
<?php
    if($result)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo "\$('#Err').hide()</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo "\$('#Err').show()</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @user1375948: No, this is not your issue and this is just an unrelated suggestion to prevent errors **in the future** with your code when you change it.

Comment: @NADH: Technically this answer is wrong because for that usage of `$` it does not have to be escaped. (But your good intentions a clear, just FYI).

Comment: I have Got It But There Is A little problem i am using this code in post with action on default page  when submit is clicked and i print the Err Tag Than There Will Be A very Short delay The Page Reloads Again And It Is Hidden Again As By default It Is Hidden when i print it through alert() delay occurs and i can see the printed tag but i want to do it without alert() function 
Kindly tell Me

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotations, your double quotations are rendering $('#Err') as a PHP variable

```
<?php
    if($result)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo '$(\'#Err\').hide()</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo '$(\'#Err\').show()</script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($result)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             $("#Err").hide()</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
              $("#Err").show()</script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is more understandable and uses less processing:

```
<!-- this is your php script with your html layout -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if($result === true): ?>
        $("#Err").hide();
    <?php else: ?>
        $("#Err").show();
    <?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

Try not to use echo. It's a good practice for PHP. If you really want to increase your php productivity, I highly recommend [the Codeigniter framework](http://www.codeigniter.com). Give it a try =).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some debugging, look into the source of your HTML that get's generated:

```
<?php
    // debug code:
    var_dump($result); die('This place has been reached');

    // normal code:
    printf("<script language=\"javascript\">\n\$('#Err').%s()\n</script>"
           , $result ? 'hide' : 'show');
?>
```

When you execute this, things will go wrong, but you can see what `$result` contains so to debug your script. If it does not display that inside the HTML source, it means that your code is not executed at all and your problem lies somewhere else.